# GWT Listbox Multi Select

Tags: java, gwt

I need to add a listbox / combobox which allows the user to choose several values.

I know there is one already available in the GWT API
[ListBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.html)
with isMultipleSelect() set to true. But I am not getting any direct way to get all selected reocrds from list box.

Some tutorials on google are sugeesting implement `ChangeHandler`'s `onChange`method.

I think there should be some other way.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own small subclass of `ListBox` offering a method like

```
public LinkedList<Integer> getSelectedItems() {
    LinkedList<Integer> selectedItems = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        if (isItemSelected(i)) {
            selectedItems.add(i);
        }
    }
    return selectedItems;
}
```

The GWT API does not offer a direct way.

Comment: I was thinking something like this.. but not by creating subclass. I liked this. Thanks..

Answer (score 5):

You can go through the items in the `ListBox` and call `isItemSelected(int)` to see if that item is selected.

Comment: +1 because this is actually mentioned in the javadoc of `getSelectedIndex()`: If multiple items are selected, this method will return the first selected item (isItemSelected(int)) can be used to query individual items).

Comment: @Zoltan: for this I need to traverse whole list and check for the same. Which I do not want to prefer

Comment: @zoobs: It also mentioned that.. "If multiple items are selected, this method will return the first selected item"

Comment: Exactly. And the 2nd part of the doc means that you will have to use `getSelectedIndex()` for more than one selected item.

Comment: @Hardik That is why it is suggested to use the 'ChangeHandler'. The third option might be to extend the ListBox the way you want, but it is not worth it

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to subclass the listbox, the following shows how to get the selected items from outside:

```
public void getSelectedItems(Collection<String> selected, ListBox listbox) {
        HashSet<Integer> indexes = new HashSet<Integer>();
        while (listbox.getSelectedIndex() >= 0) {
            int index = listbox.getSelectedIndex();
            listbox.setItemSelected(index, false);
            String selectedElem = listbox.getItemText(index);
            selected.add(selectedElem);
            indexes.add(index);
        }
        for (Integer index : indexes) {
            listbox.setItemSelected(index, true);
        }
    }
```

After the method has run the selected collection will contain the selected elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question is more than one year old now and I no longer work on GWT

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through all items in the `ListBox`. The only shortcut is to iterate from the first selected item using `getSelectedItem()` which return the first selected item in multi select `ListBox`.

```
public List<String> getSelectedValues() {
    LinkedList<String> values = new LinkedList<String>();
    if (getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
        for (int i = getSelectedIndex(); i < getItemCount(); i++) {
            if (isItemSelected(i)) {
                values.add(getValue(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```