# how to allow multi select on gwt combobox

Tags: gwt, combobox, listbox, gxt

I have combo-box and i want to allow multiple selection on it
how to do that??

```
newEmployee = new ComboBox<NctrUserDTO>();
           newEmployee.setFieldLabel("Employee");  
           newEmployee.setDisplayField(NctrUserDTO.NAME);  
           newEmployee.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
           newEmployee.setEditable(true);
           newEmployee.setStore(employeeList);  
           newEmployee.setMaxHeight(200);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which API's ComboBox you're using since vanilla GWT doesn't have a ComboBox, but I'd guess it's not possible to do this unless you change the ComboBox class itself/write an actual MultiSelectComboBox class. Unless your version happens to have an "enableMultiSelect" method already in-built, but you probably wouldn't be asking here then.

If it helps, [I found this thread which seems similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248213/gwt-listbox-multi-select) to what you're describing.